# Apple Generic Versioning creates a linker error (missing _main)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I enabled Apple Generic Versioning in my Xcode 4.3.2 project. When I attempt to build the project, I get a linker error stating that there is no _main symbol found.

has anyone seen this problem and do you know a solution?

Only workaround is to remove the Generate Versioning Source Filename, but I still get a build error when I do this.

Comment: I've just started messing with this myself, trying to get a build number available to my code.  I changed the pop-up in Build Settings from blank to apple-generic and I'm not getting any errors.  I did also set the Current Project Version (in debug) to 1.0. Are you further along on this now?

Comment: Nope. I did see that there was mention of this on a phonegap/cordova forum somewhere but I've moved on.